# How to delete blobs from blob storage using Lifecycle management

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-storage-delete

I have a storage account and inside that I have container "mycontainer"

I have two virtual folders
preview and final

I want to configure life cycle rule to delete all blobs from preview folder which is created a day ago along with that
I want to configure another rule that deletes all blobs from final which is created a day ago, only if the blob has an index tag "candelete" : "true"

When I tried configuring Lifecycle rule, it get deletes blobs from preview, but not from final

My rules looks like

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "deletepreview",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "mycontainer/preview"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "deletefinal",
      "type": "Lifecycle",
      "definition": {
        "actions": {
          "baseBlob": {
            "delete": {
              "daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 1
            }
          }
        },
        "filters": {
          "blobIndexMatch": [
            {
              "name": "candelete",
              "op": "==",
              "value": "true"
            }
          ],
          "blobTypes": [
            "blockBlob"
          ],
          "prefixMatch": [
            "mycontainer/final"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Blob Lifecycle Management

I have created blob1 container having t1 and t2 folders as follows

[image]

[image]

there are two ways to manage blob lifecycle through portal and through code. following method illustrates creating rules through portal

1. in storage account created go to lifecycle management -> add rules
   we also have code view where we can edit code

[image]

2. Give Rule name, Rule scope (limit blob as filters), Blob type (Block blobs) , Blob subtype (Base blob) and next

[image]

3. Give conditions as required in this case Base blobs were = Created, days 0(for demonstration), Then = Delete the blob

[image]

4. In next filter set give Blob prefix as container_name/folder_name and click add

[image]

5. For adding filters with Indexed tag make sure to add relevant Blob index tag while creating the file or can be updated after creating the file under the properties

[image]

6. Similarly add another rule with required details and in filter set tab give appropriate Blob prefix and add the key/value under Blob index match then add

[image]

7. The two are created as seen in image

[image]

8. In code view tab the code for the created rules is automatically generated as follows

```
{

"rules": [

{

"enabled": true,

"name": "deletet1",

"type": "Lifecycle",

"definition": {

"actions": {

"baseBlob": {

"delete": {

"daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 0

}

}

},

"filters": {

"blobTypes": [

"blockBlob"

],

"prefixMatch": [

"blob1/t1"

]

}

}

},

{

"enabled": true,

"name": "deletet2",

"type": "Lifecycle",

"definition": {

"actions": {

"baseBlob": {

"delete": {

"daysAfterCreationGreaterThan": 0

}

}

},

"filters": {

"blobIndexMatch": [

{

"name": "frp",

"op": "==",

"value": "true"

}

],

"blobTypes": [

"blockBlob"

],

"prefixMatch": [

"blob1/t2"

]

}

}

}

]

}
```

> ***Note: I noticed that sometimes the files will be deleted after one day, it just takes more than 24 hours to process the rule. In my case
> as I set the rule to 0, they are deleted within a day.***

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did too. But for me, sometimes it will execute only one rule, though I have two configured with filters.